# Text at bottom in DIV without using Display:Table-Cell in CSS

Tags: css

is there any other proper way to display text at bottom because with Display:Table-Cell, I can't use margin property.

```
div.Product2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('../images/cp_bg.png') no-repeat center 10px #008f00;

}
```

Comment: Can you use 2 div's or does it exclusively need to be 1 div?

Comment: Please include the HTML in your question as well.

Comment: If you want the text at the bottom, you'd probably need to remove the bottom-padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I believe you could do this without `table-cell` would be using multiple `div`s. You have a choice to either keep the `table-cell` and place it inside a wrapper `div` or just put your text into a child `div`

```css
div.Product2 {
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('../images/cp_bg.png') no-repeat center 10px #008f00;
    position: relative;
}

div.product3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Product2">
  Some Text  
  <div class="product3">
     Bottom Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method of achieving this is to wrap your text within a containing element, like `<p>`, and apply a CSS transform. This of course won't have broad support unless you use some prefixes.

```css
.Product2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #008f00;
}

.Product2 p {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Product2">
    <p>Blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is `line-height`, since your `height` is fixed, `line-height` is a good solution. No need to change your structure. Remove `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.

```css
div.Product2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('../images/cp_bg.png') no-repeat center 10px #008f00;
    line-height:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Product2">
    Hello World!
</div>
```